# Como escribir un 'Salto de línea' en un documento desde python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Quiero que el usuario ingrese el nombre de un archivo donde haya un texto, y las palabras que contengan `'z'` y `'s'` se devuelvan como `'----'` (conservando el número de caracteres de la palabra). Luego, cuando el texto esté con las palabras que tienen `'s'` y `'z'` en modo `'----'`, quiero escribir ese nuevo texto que he creado en otro archivo cuyo nombre debe ingresar el usuario.

He conseguido hacer todo eso, pero no consigo separar el nuevo texto en frases; es decir, al abrir el documento con el nuevo texto me aparece todo escrito en una sola linea, y yo quiero que haya el mismo número de lineas que el texto original, no una sola. Por tanto, quiero añadir un 'Salto de línea' en el texto nuevo.

¿Cómo lo hago?

```
#1
def prozesatu (hitza):  #función que convierte las palabras que contienen s y z en ----
    hitza2=''
    a=0
    for hizk in hitza:
        if hizk=='s' or hizk=='z':
            a=1
        hitza2='-'+hitza2
    if a==1:
        return hitza2
    return hitza



#2
fitx1=open(input('Sartu prozesatu nahi duzun fitxategia:')) #el archivo que quiero leer
fitx2=open(input('Sartu testu prozesatua idaztea nahi duzun fitxategia:'),'w') #el archivo donde quiero escribir
testuproz=''
for lerro in fitx1:
    lerro=lerro.split()
    esaldia=''
    for hitz in lerro:
        esaldia=esaldia+' '+prozesatu(hitz)
    fitx2.write(esaldia)
    print(esaldia)
fitx1.close()
fitx2.close()
```

Comment: Podrías añadir un archivo de ejemplo, la salida que estás obteniendo y la salida que estás esperando. Sin embargo te diria que leyendo linea por linea, procesandola, añadiendo `'\n'` y escribiendo en el nuevo archivo sería suficiente.

Comment: Pero donde añado \n dentro del programa? Es que si pongo fitx2.write(\n esaldia) me da error.

Comment: porqie tienes que hacer `'\\n'`

Comment: Es `fitx2.write(esaldia + '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar saltos de linea en python, tienes de dos formas de hacerlo con triples comillas y con `"\n"`.

---

No entiendo absolutamente nada de tu código, pero lo que podrías hacer es dar el salto de linea en la linea 23 justo antes de escribirla en el archivo *(creo que era esa)* de tal manera que así no te quedara todo junto.

PD: Una buena practica es escribir código en ingles.